# What are autodoc'd plugins?

Tags: vimrc

Saw this in a .vimrc file:

```
"====[ Ensure autodoc'd plugins are supported ]===========
runtime plugin/_autodoc.vim
```

Any idea on what autodoc'd docs are and how they work?

Comment: `:helpgrep autodoc` does not yield any results, so I don't think it's a Vim feature.

Comment: the author's video: Damian Conway - "A Vim Environment For Perl Developers" https://youtu.be/oka4wcsrg0c